# How to use APPEND CATENATE in GMAIL

Tags: c#, gmail, imap

Can somebody explain how to use IMAP APPEND CATENATE command? I already searched the internet. What I would appreciate is single command to append some string to existing draft with UID 1.

I tried : $$ APPEND [Gmail]/Drafts (\Seen \Draft) CATENATE (URL \"[Gmail]/Drafts;UIDVALIDITY=385759045/;UID=1/;section=HEADER\" TEXT {10}\r\n

But with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't.  It is not a supported extension on Gmail's IMAP server:

```
> a CAPABILITY
< * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE CONDSTORE ESEARCH UTF8=ACCEPT LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS APPENDLIMIT=35882577
```